# Is it possible to set default value to display in DynamicControl? Not

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dynamic-controls

In asp.net webform I have a FormView with DynamicControl. How do I set a default value for issuedDate?

```
   <asp:FormView runat="server"....>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="issuedDate" runat="server">Issued date:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="issuedDate" DataField="IssuedDate" Mode="Edit" />
            ....
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <p>
                No Data found.
            </p>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

Comment: Did you try data bound event? In that check for insert item, access your control and set default value.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri like this ? `protected void issuedDate_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((DynamicControl)sender).SetAttribute("Text", "03/03/2017");
        }`

Comment: No. Form view's item data bound event.

Comment: I managed to do  `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="issuedDateTextBox" text='<%# Bind("IssuedDate") %>' OnDataBinding="issuedDateTextBox_DataBinding" />`    `protected void issuedDateTextBox_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
        }` unfortunately not for DynamicControl

Comment: Not this way. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamicControl didn't work. So I used TextBox instead of DynamicControl.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="IssuedDateTextBox" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Bind("IssuedDate") %>' />
```

Added myForm_DataBound

```
protected void myForm_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myForm.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)myForm.FindControl("IssuedDateTextBox");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text.Trim()))
        {
            //set default value - TODAY date
            tb.Text = String.Format("{0:yyyy}{0:MM}{0:dd}", DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to access your control as below,

```
protected void ItemsFormView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    If (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert){
        DataRowView dataRow = ((DataRowView)FormView1.DataItem);
        if (Convert.ToInt16(dataRow["ClStk"]) <= 0)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("lblStock");
            lbl.CssClass = "changefont";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in "  occurs for `protected void myForm_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormViewRow row = (FormViewRow)(myForm.DataItem);
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)myForm.FindControl("issuedDate");
            tb.Text = "04/03/2016"; 
        }`

Comment: my bad i had no check. now I added the check  `if (myForm.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
            { FormViewRow row = (FormViewRow)(myForm.DataItem); TextBox tb = (TextBox)myForm.FindControl("issuedDate"); tb.Text = "04/03/2016"; }` and get another exception Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.DynamicData.DynamicControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

Comment: So hope you solve this issue, its conversion error. Convert your control to proper type and assign value.